# make zend clear cache for every visit?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an application developed in zend framework. I need to make sure browser is
not using cache each time it loads my site. Is there a way to make zend clear cache for every visit? i'm looking for possibly ini setting .

Comment: Not so much a Zend Framework issue. More of a general web-caching - hence HTTP - issue. It's all about the HTTP headers you send directing the client not to cache. Still, are you sure you really want to suppress client-side caching, so broadly? It's one of the most basic ways to improve performance, especially for static assets like images, javascript, and stylesheets. Or, do you simply need a method to make sure that each visitor is using the most current assets after you do an update?

Comment: Is this strictly for development?  No caching in a live environment is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you use sessions (`Zend_Session`), PHP sends those headers automatically.

If you don't use sessions, inside a Zend controller, you can use this:

```
<?php

class SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    function indexAction(){
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Cache-Control','no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',1);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Expires','Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',1);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Pragma','no-cache',1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a good idea, but you could start from reading this:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

at the 14.9 paragraph. There is the complete explanation of the cache control.

For example, if you want to ensure that the user will see always the latest version you could set a short expiration time to the cache entries...

Be aware: if you don't let the browser to cache contents, every access it will be slow as the first loading... (especially if there are many images and "heavy" objects)

Good programming!